# SQL Azure Elastic Scale - reference table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I am not sure if I understand the idea of reference tables correctly. In my mind it is a table that contains the same data in every shard. Am I wrong? I am asking because I have no idea how should I insert data to the reference table to make the data multiply in every shard. Or maybe it is impossible? Can anyone clarify this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the idea of a Reference Table is that the same data is contained on every shard.   If you have small numbers of shards and data changes are rare, you can open multiple connections in your application and apply the changes to multiple DBs simultaneously.   Or you can construct a management script that iterates periodically across all shards to update reference data or performs a bulk-insert of a fresh image of rows.

The new feature previewing in Azure SQL Database called Elastic DB Jobs, which allows you to define a SQL script for operations that you want to take place on all shards, and then runs the script asynchronously with eventual completion guarantees.   You can potentially use this to update reference tables.  Details on the feature are [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-jobs-overview/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about insert using MultiShardCommand but ExecuteNonQuery is not supported. I was wondering if there is any better solution than iteration on shards and insert into every shard.

Comment: You can still perform inserts by using ExecuteReader and submitting an insert clause or StoredProc call.  You will get an empty result set.   However keep in mind that inserts or updates using MultiShardCommand is not transactional across shards, so you will need to pay attention to any error messages that are returned in the per-shard error collection and take corrective action...